# getting data of 2 columns from one table

Tags: mysql

i have one table having this structure . Table name `event`

```
 id
 user_id
 description
 creater_id
```

the `user_id` and `creater_id` data is present in the `credential` table

```
 id
 fname
 lname
```

what i am trying to do is to make a query through which i can get the `fname` and `lanme` of `user_id` column and `creater_id` column from the credential table .

The linking is like this

```
 event.user_id = credential.id
 event.creater_id = credential.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but you have to know that you can join the same table more then once (just add an alias).

Following query will return four columns: `fname`/`lname` pair for `user_id` and `creator_id` from event table.

```
SELECT
    c1.fname as user_fname, c1.lname as user_lname,
    c2.fname as creator_fname, c2.lname as creator_lname
FROM
    event e
JOIN
    credentials c1 ON c1.id = e.user_id
JOIN
    credentials c2 ON c2.id = e.creator_id
```